# How to create an Angular Flex-Layout stylebuilder to generate a default fxLayoutGap?

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to create a style builder to generate a default `fxLayoutGap` if none is specified, as outlined [here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Style-Builders#overriding-defaults):

This is my setup

**module**

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [{
        provide: LayoutGapStyleBuilder,    // when default is requested
        useClass: DefaultLayoutGapStyleBuilder  // provide instead custom builder
    }]
})
```

**default-layout-gap-style-builder.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LayoutGapParent, LayoutGapStyleBuilder, StyleDefinition } from '@angular/flex-layout';

@Injectable()
export class DefaultLayoutGapStyleBuilder extends LayoutGapStyleBuilder {
    buildStyles(input: string, parent: LayoutGapParent): StyleDefinition {

        input = input || '10px';    

        return super.buildStyles(input, parent); // THIS RETURNS { }
    }
}
```

**view.html**

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutGap>
```

Everything seems to be hooked up correctly, but the call to `super.buildStyles` is not returning anything so a default gap style of `10px` is not applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/src/lib/flex/layout-gap/layout-gap.ts#L50) if the value you pass in, '10px' in this case, does not end in `' grid';` than it will return the empty object and not give you the gap layout.  I'm guessing you will want to use a different builder or input for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

from @CaerusKaru: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/1011

may also need to override sideEffect:

```
sideEffect(gapValue: string, _styles: StyleDefinition, parent: LayoutGapParent): void { 
  gapValue = gapValue ? gapValue : '0rem'; 
  super.sideEffect( gapValue,_styles,parent ); 
}
```

or as in 1011 @rovercoder could workaround with MediaMarshaller